# Appending text to the end of a previous line with sed

Tags: sed

and thanks for considering my question!

I have nagios config files in this format:

```
define host{
    use             generic-camera
    host_name       camera_7
    alias           camera facing the 7th door at headquarters
    address         172.16.202.21
    parents         hq_switch
    hostgroups      cameras,fixed-cameras
    }
```

What I would like to accomplish is to use sed to match the IP address, and append text to the line before it. I've seen plenty of suggestions how to append text to a line that matches a regex, but not how to append to the previous. I would like to append the MAC address of the IP listed under address to the alias line. This is what I would like things to look after sed has been run:

```
define host{
    use             generic-camera
    host_name       camera_7
    alias           camera facing the 7th door at headquarters MAC 00:01:02:aa:bb:cc
    address         172.16.202.21
    parents         hq_switch
    hostgroups      cameras,fixed-cameras
    }
```

The reason it needs to match the IP is for a bash script to get the correct MAC for the device from its address.

I have awk available as well, should this be a case where awk writes cleaner than sed.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another sed to try:

```
sed '/alias/{N; /[^0-9]172\.16\.202\.21$/s/\n/ MAC 00:01:02:aa:bb:cc&/;}' file
```

Comment: This worked wonderfully, and I Was able to incorporate it into a shell script that matched MAC addresses to the IPs, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
awk 'NR>1{if ($0 ~ "^ *address") print x " MAC 00:01:02:aa:bb:cc"; else print x};
   {x=$0} END{print x}' in-file
```

#### EDIT: Getting Mac address from IP address via script instead of hard coding:

```
awk 'NR>1{if ($0 ~ "^ *address") {"arp "$2 | getline line; split(line, tok, " ");
    print x " MAC " tok[4];} else print x};{x=$0} END{print x}' in-file
```

Comment: I was excited by how short this is, but it doesn't work because of my description. The base file has hundreds of hosts and IPs, and it would put the same MAC for every one of the IPs. I believe however that changing your regex from ($0 ~ "^ *address") to the more specific ($0 ~ "172.16.202.21") it should work.

Comment: @user2149818: If you have to handle lots of IP addresses then I would suggest getting their Mac address using arp command and then appending it as I suggested above.

Comment: I think something is off with differences in our shells maybe? When I run your edit, I get "/bin/sh: 172.16.202.21: not found" for every IP address in the original file. I've been working towards something like this, but it only works for IP at a time, not every IP. awk "NR>1{if (\$0 ~ \"^ *address* * ${i}\$\") print x \" MAC ${mac}\"; else print x};{x=\$0} END{print x}" in-file

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -n '
  ## Set label 'a'.
  :a

  ## Read and save every line until we find the IP.
  /172\.16\.202\.21/! { 
    N
    ba 
  }

  ## Append the MAC just before the last '\n' (previous line).
  s/^\(.*\)\n/\1 MAC 00:01:02:aa:bb:cc\n/

  ## Print all saved until now.
  p

  ## Remove all printed.
  s/^.*$//

  ## Enter a loop to save all content until end of file.
  :b
  $! { 
    N
    bb 
  }

  ## Remove the additional '\n' added by the 'N' command and print.
  s/\n//
  p

' infile
```

It yields:

```
define host{
    use             generic-camera
    host_name       camera_7
    alias           camera facing the 7th door at headquarters MAC 00:01:02:aa:bb:cc
    address         172.16.202.21
    parents         hq_switch
    hostgroups      cameras,fixed-cameras
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks like it will work, trying to script it together with bash to get the right mac with its respective IP now.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't feel the need to escape the dots in the IP address field, there are no spots in the file that would have long strings of numbers that weren't IP addresses, so I just ripped the . matching out to simplify things on me. The shell script coupled with the sed line I asked for help with looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for (( h = 200; h <= 204; h++ ))
do
for (( j = 1; j <= 150; j++ ))
do
i="172.16.$h.$j"
mac=`grep $i\  /proc/net/arp |awk '{print $4}'`

sed "/alias/{N; /[^0-9]$i\$/s/\n/ MAC $mac&/;}" $1 >> ${1}.new1
done
done

grep -A4 -B4 MAC ${1}.new1 > ${1}.new2
sed -i "s/^--//g" ${1}.new2

sed -n -e '1,/host/p' /usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/${1} |sed '$d' > ${1}.top
grep -B4 -A999 HOST\ GROUP\ DEF /usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/${1} > ${1}.tail

mkdir -p new
cat ${1}.top ${1}.new2 ${1}.tail > new/${1}
```

I'm sure there are cleaner ways to do the same, but this is what I got to work with my current (admittedly low level) skills. In particular, each of the output files only changes 1 host, and there were sometimes hundreds per file, so the kludge of splitting them all out with only 1 of hundreds of hosts changed, then grepping for that single change to spit it elsewhere should be cleaned up, but should someone else end up with this issue this should work, at least it did for me but YMMV.